# Using U-SQL MultiLevelJsonExtractor gives Error: Path returned multiple tokens

Tags: u-sql

I am using the MultiLevelJsonExtractor forked on Git by kotvisbj, When I put a Path that contains an array (body.header.items[*] or body.header.items) into the JsonPaths parameter string, I get a "Error: Path returned multiple tokens". Is there a way to extract the paths in code so I can get an array like when using the Root? I tried to explain this the best way I could, I don't have excellent c# skills, it's been a few years.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to ask the owner of the branch to see if he can advise you. I assume that his code expects a single token only and not an array of tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably achieve what you need by using code similar to this: [U-SQL - Extract data from json-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147932/u-sql-extract-data-from-json-array)