# JSONPath: Extract single dict with keys and values

Tags: json, jsonpath, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a U-SQL application that runs in the Azure Data Lake environment. It's supposed to process a file full of JSON data that looks like this, except for being a lot more than two rows in real life.

```
[
{"reports" : {"direction": "FWD", "drive": "STOPS", "frob_variable": 0}},
{"reports" : {"direction": "FWD", "drive": "CRANKS", "frob_variable": -3}}
]
```

In that Data Lake job, I have the following line:

```
@json =
EXTRACT direction string, drive string, frob_variable int FROM @"/input/file.json"
USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor("reports");
```

When I dump the contents of that `@json` variable to a text file I get empty values: zero-length strings and zero-valued integers. I do get the correct number of output rows though, so it must be iterating over all my input.

A bit of poking around the source code to the `JsonExtractor` shows me that my specified JsonPath value ("reports") seems to be returning the "reports" key with the embedded dict. If I try a JsonPath value of "reports.*" I do get the embedded values (e.g., `{ "FWD", "STOPS", 0 }`) but I really wanted the keys to go along with them so `SELECT direction, drive, frob_variable` would return something useful.

Long story short, I'm looking for a way to pull the keys *and* values from that inner dict. Thus my desired output from the `EXTRACT` would be a rowset whose columns are "direction", "drive", and "frob_variable" and whose values are as indicated in the source data. It seems like there should be a JsonPath solution or a simple workaround in U-SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@extract =
     EXTRACT 
         reports String
     FROM @"/input/file.json"
     USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

@relation =
    SELECT
     Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(reports)
     AS report
    FROM @extract;

@fields =
    SELECT 
       report["direction"] AS direction,
       report["drive"] AS drive,
       Int32.Parse(report["frob_variable"]) AS frob
    FROM @relation;
```

See also [U-SQL - Extract data from json-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147932/u-sql-extract-data-from-json-array)

Comment: Aha! That's what I was looking for. Json-array extraction!