# How to use JSON file formats in the context of Azure Data Lake Analytics respectively usql

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql, data-lake

I have a JSON input that looks like

```
{
    "sessionId": 1234,
    "deviceId": "MAC:1234",
    "IoTHub": {
        "MessageId": "1234-1234-1234-1234"
    }
}
```

How can I extract the values of `sessionId`, `deviceId` and `MessageId` in a Azure Datalake Analytics usql script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to use JSON file formats in the context of Azure Data Lake Analytics respectively usql

### Set Up process

- Download the repo from [1]

  - Open the solution in `.\Examples\DataFormats\Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.sln`
  - Build the solution
  - Get `.\Examples\DataFormats\Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.dll`
  - Get `.\Examples\DataFormats\Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll`
- In ADLS create a folder where to store the assemblies (e.g. `.\assemblies`)

  - Create a sample file in the folder if it disappears (happened to me)
- With Visual Studio:

  - Add both files to the folder of the ADLA solution (e.g. `.\lib\...`)
  - Open `Cloud Explorer`, navigate to the ADLA Database -> Assemblies -> right click and register the assemblies

    - Store the assemblies in the folder created before in ADLS
- Reference the assemblies as can be seen below

### Usage

#### JSON Input Data

- Use the Extractor as e.g. shown below

  - For more information see [2] and [3]

## Resources

[1] [GitHub Azure USQL](https://github.com/Azure/usql)

[2] [GitHub Azure USQL DataFormats](https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats)

[3] [U-SQL - Extract data from json-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147932/u-sql-extract-data-from-json-array)

## U-SQL Script

```
DECLARE @localDevelopment bool = true;

IF @localDevelopment == true THEN
    DROP ASSEMBLY IF EXISTS [Newtonsoft.Json];
    DROP ASSEMBLY IF EXISTS [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats];
    CREATE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json] FROM @"/lib/Newtonsoft.Json.dll";
    CREATE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats] FROM @"/lib/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.dll";
    DECLARE @input string = @"/data/input.json";
    DECLARE @output string = @"/data/output.csv";
ELSE
    DECLARE @input string = @"/data/input.json";
    DECLARE @output string = @"/data/output.csv";
END;

REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Newtonsoft.Json];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats]; 

//Define schema of file, must map all columns
//Names must match keys
@extractDataFirstLevel = 
    EXTRACT sessionId int,
            deviceId string,
            IoTHub string
            //Date DateTime
    FROM @input
    USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

@selectData =
    SELECT sessionId,
           deviceId,
           Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonFunctions.JsonTuple(IoTHub)["MessageId"] AS messageId
    FROM @extractDataFirstLevel;

OUTPUT @selectData
TO @output
USING Outputters.Csv();
```